# Scraping Flickr with Selenium/Beautiful soup in Python - ABSWP

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm going through Automate Boring Stuff with Python and I'm stuck at the chapter about downloading data from the internet. One of the tasks is download photos for a given keyword from Flickr.

I have a massive problem with scraping this site. I've tried BeautifulSoup (which I think is not appropriate in this case as it uses Javascript) and Selenium. Looking at the html I think that I should locate 'overlay' class. However no matter which option I use (`find_element_by_class_name`, `...by_text`, `...by_partial_text`) I am not able to find these elements (I get: ".

Could you please help me to clarify what I'm doing wrong? I'd be also grateful for any materials that could help me understadt such cases better. Thanks!

Here's my simple code:

```
import sys
search_keywords = sys.argv[1]
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get(f'https://www.flickr.com/search/?text={search_keywords}')
elems = browser.find_element_by_class_name("overlay")
print(elems)
elems.click()
```

Sample keywords I type in shell: "industrial design interior"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting any error message? With Selenium it's useful to surround your code in try/except blocks.

What are you trying to do exactly, download the photos? With a bit of re-writing

```
try:
     options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
     #options.add_argument('--headless')
     driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options)
     search_keywords = "cars"
     driver.get(f'https://www.flickr.com/search/?text={search_keywords}')
     time.sleep(1)

 except Exception as e:
     print("Error loading search results page" + str(e))

 try:
     elems = driver.find_element_by_class_name("overlay")
     print(elems)
     elems.click()
     time.sleep(5)
 except Exception as e:
     print(str(e))
```

Loads the page as expected and then clicks on the photo, taking us to [This Page](https://www.flickr.com/photos/parismadrid/5287262740/in/photolist-94dB1q-aShvfH-9AGRGE-XAYHHB-psUU8x-8Lv7G9-aadHcT-911yKV-9AGRD5-5A7tqy-9ADWRB-da7ZuD-asDV3C-VBdKXq-njkcCr-9AGRJq-94dAXG-dFGFVh-85KVXX-9ADWNp-eeULGH-amt7Ks-85KVTi-p5tgZ9-aVHNat-b3xQRt-nFWYRZ-axqX4v-83iJ8d-atZY83-mR3P84-avJxh7-7Z4Jt9-rh6uDT-et3gjH-9VQxgD-a2Anf1-4cV54o-6M8n6W-dQoswE-n5Yep6-4T7AKT-cTnEmj-ak2uVQ-qxdwrf-7obBhB-fqX6s6-geJEnd-2YRRoe-h4hJ7G%22This%20Page%22)
I would be able to help more if you could go into more detail of what you're wanting to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - code works very well :) Yes, I'm trying to download the photos. I think that the highest resolution is saved under `class="zoom-large"` in the subpage. I've noticed that after adding `time.sleep` my code also works. I didn't realise that I have to add this. I thought that Selenium has some kind of inbuilt intelligence and it knows when page has fully loaded.

Comment: you have to explicitly make selenium to wait. check for `element_to_be_clickable` in https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Thanks, after reading the article this 'waiting' aspect is clear for me.